# Handling Profile Dependencies using Custom Value Resolvers (Automapper 8.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

Using automapper 8.0 with a custom value resolver and dependencies.
My source class contains a boolean property which have to be translated into a string in my destination class. To do that, I have to use a custom value resolver which have the service injected.

I've followed that link to do what I wanted : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51043.automapper-handling-profile-dependencies-using-custom-value-resolvers.aspx

Since the new version of AutoMapper, ResolveUsing have been replaced by MapFrom. So do I but I get this error is shown when I'm using the resolver with "MapFrom" : There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sourceMember' of 'IPathConfigurationExpression.MapFrom(Expression>)'

```cs
// The resolver
public class MyResolver : IValueResolver<SourceType, DestType, string>
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    public MyResolver(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public string Resolve(SourceType source, DestType destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.MyProperty? _myService.GetById(1) : _myService.GetById(2);
    }
}

// The call
CreateMap<DestType, SourceType>()
     .ForPath(dest => dest.Obj1.Obj2.myProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver>());
```

Did I forget something ?

Comment: Use ForMember, not ForPath.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code example (sorry for the lack). I need to use "ForPath" because the targeted property is nested.

Comment: Use intellisense to understand what overloads exist, because ForPath is not the same as ForMember, only a small subset is available.

Comment: Well seen. It seems ForPath doesn't manage that extension. :/ Any idea how to deal with that? (I mean I need to call a service depending on the boolean source property)

Comment: You can always create a map for some inner class so you can use ForMember. Worst case scenario, fallback to AfterMap for the main map.